# How does a list end in nil?

Tags: list

I believe Emacs lists have `nil` at their end.
That said, I was trying to test examples.
Can anyone tell the difference between `a` and `b`?

```el
(setq a '(foo))  
(setq b '(foo nil))  

;; Returns nil and (nil), respectively.
(cdr a)
(cdr b)
```

Comment: a is `(foo . nil)`.  b is `(foo . (nil . nil))`.

Comment: And `(cdr nil)` and `(car nil)` return `nil` (by convention, for convenience).

Comment: @Toothrot or OP: Please consider posting that as an answer.

Comment: `a` is a list with one element: `foo`.  `b` is a list with two elements: `foo` and `nil`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in a sense true that a *proper list* ends in `nil`, but
not in the sense that the last element of every proper list is `nil`.
It is the cdr of the innermost cons of the proper list that is `nil`.  A
cons is a car-cdr pair.  A proper list is a nest of conses, or rather, a proper list is either nil or a cons
whose cdr is a proper list.  So a finite proper list is a nest
of conses whose innermost cons's cdr is nil.  Its elements are its cars.  The proper list
`(a b c)` is a cons whose car is `a` and whose cdr is `(b c)`,
whose cdr is `(c)`, whose cdr is `nil`.  The last element is
`c`, not `nil`; but the last (or innermost) cdr is indeed `nil`;
this is what ends a proper list.

In dotted-pair notation, which shows the cons structure of a list, `(a b c)` is 
`(a . (b . (c . nil)))`.

A list simpliciter is either `nil` or a cons whose cdr is not
necessarily a list.

Your `a` is `(foo . nil)` and your `b` is `(foo . (nil . nil))`.

And `(cdr b)` is `(nil)` because `(nil . nil)` is `(nil)`, the
list whose only element is `nil`.

For more on conses, evaluate `(info "(elisp) Cons Cell Type")`.

Comment: I think it would be useful to link to [`(info "(elisp) Cons Cell Type")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Cons-Cell-Type.html) and subnodes.

Comment: @phils, Graham calls it _dot notation._

Comment: @Toothrot Fair enough -- please change it back if you prefer.  It's always "dotted pair notation" in the elisp manual, which is why I edited that, but I think it's good either way.